# consulta sql filtrar por diferentes fechas

Tags: mysql

[image]
Buenas necesito obtener los datos de la siguiente imagen 
Nombre del campo y numero de tickets que tenga cada campo por fecha

Mi consulta sql es la siguiente

```
    select empresa.nombre,count(id_incidencia) tickets
    from incidencias
    INNER JOIN empresa ON empresa.id_empresa = incidencias.id_cliente
    where created_at>= "2019-01-01" AND created_at<= "2019-1-31"
    group by empresa.nombre  
    ORDER BY `tickets`  DESC
```

Funciona pero solo retorno los de enero necesito retornar todos los meses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una técnica común para obtener un reporte en columnas como el que buscas es, en cada columna, sumar 1 cuando el registro pertenece al mes que representa la columna, y 0 o `null` si no lo es.

Siguiendo esta técnica, la siguiente consulta, daría un resultado como el que buscas:

```
select   empresa.nombre
       , sum(case when month(incidencias.created_at) = 1 then 1 end) Enero
       , sum(case when month(incidencias.created_at) = 2 then 1 end) Febrero
       , sum(case when month(incidencias.created_at) = 3 then 1 end) Marzo
       , sum(case when month(incidencias.created_at) = 4 then 1 end) Abril
       , sum(case when month(incidencias.created_at) = 5 then 1 end) Mayo
       , sum(case when month(incidencias.created_at) = 6 then 1 end) Junio
       , sum(case when month(incidencias.created_at) = 7 then 1 end) Julio
       , sum(case when month(incidencias.created_at) = 8 then 1 end) Agosto
       , sum(case when month(incidencias.created_at) = 9 then 1 end) Septiembre
       , sum(case when month(incidencias.created_at) = 10 then 1 end) Octubre
       , sum(case when month(incidencias.created_at) = 11 then 1 end) Noviembre
       , sum(case when month(incidencias.created_at) = 12 then 1 end) Diciembre
  from empresa
       left join incidencias 
              on incidencias.id_cliente = empresa.id_empresa 
             and incidencias.created_at between '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31'
 group by empresa.nombre
```

Si observas, en el from, he utilizado primero la tabla de empresas y he hecho un `left join` con la de incidencias. Esto provocará que aparezcan todas las empresas, hayan o no tenido incidentes durante el año.

Si se quiere que aparezcan solamente las empresas que han tenido incidentes, yo cambiaría la clausula `from` de la consulta y trasladaría la condición del fechas al `where` algo así:

```
  from empresa
       inner join incidencias 
              on incidencias.id_cliente = empresa.id_empresa 
 where incidencias.created_at between '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31'
```